# pod repo push [private repo] encountered a version error

Tags: tags, cocoapods

Recently, I was going about modularization of my company's iOS app, and we chose to use cocoapods to manage modules.
----- this is background -----
Yesterday, I tried to upload a module to our private spec repo, thus I executed the following command (in the podspec directory)

```
pod repo push [private repo name] --allow-warnings --sources='[private repo git address]' --verbose --use-libraries
```

However, when the cocoapods was downloading some private dependencies, I found some of the dependencies' version were not the latest, which result in the failure of `xcodebuild` step (Because we changed the name of some functions in the latest version).
The module's podspec file dependency part: (I didn't specify the version of dependencies, cause I want latest)

```
...
s.dependency 'HomeJump'
...
```

(The latest version of `HomeJump` in my private spec repo is 0.1.6, but every time I executed `pod repo push xxx`, the version of `HomeJump` it installed was 0.1.5)
PS:
When I execute `pod spec lint xxx`, the `HomeJump` version is 0.1.6, which is correct.
And I've already tried to run `pod repo update`, `rm -rf /Library/Cache/Cocoapods`, reinstall my private repo ...

Somebody has any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well... finally I found out the reason.
Every time the `pod repo push xxx` command is executed, cocoapods will find the corresponding version for each dependency in a automatically created spec repo, which has different name with your private spec repo (the name form is kind of like 'git server name - group name - repo name'). This temporary spec repo is related to your private spec repo.

The solution is: **delete the temporary spec repo and run `pod repo push xxx` again**

1. list your cocoapods repo by running `pod repo list`
2. find the one which is not created manually by yourself which is also related to your private spec repo
3. run `rm -rf [the repo directory name]`